# Protocol to View Controller doesn't fire any defined methods

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

I've created a protocol and matching delegate.
The methods I've defined don't seem to fire, but throw up no errors.

ResourceScrollView.h

```
//Top of File
@protocol ResourceScrollViewDelegate
    - (void)loadPDFWithItem:(NSString *)filePath;
@end
//Within Interface
id<ResourceScrollViewDelegate> _scrollViewDelegate;
//Outside Interface
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<ResourceScrollViewDelegate> scrollViewDelegate;
```

ResourceScrollView.m

```
//Inside Implementation
@synthesize scrollViewDelegate=_scrollViewDelegate;
//Within a button tapped method
[_scrollViewDelegate loadPDFWithItem:filePath];
```

ResourcesViewController.h

```
//Top of File
#import "ResourceScrollView.h"
@interface ResourcesViewController : UIViewController <ResourceScrollViewDelegate>
```

ResourcesViewController.m

```
//Inside Implementation
- (void)loadPDFWithItem:(NSString *)filePath{
    NSLog(@"PDF %@",filePath);
}
```

For some reason I'm not getting the NSLog.
There are no errors or crashes, it simply does not fire.

Have I made any errors that could account for this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you forgotten to set the `ResourcesViewController` Object to `scrollViewDelegate` property?

Comment: What do you mean? How would I do this?

Comment: Ah never mind, I've got it! `[resourceScrollView setScrollViewDelegate:self];`